# XML schema in VS 2013 map to an 834 EDI. to a non looping segment

Tags: xml, mapping, schema, edi

I have built an XML schema in VS 2013 and am attempting to map to an 834 EDI. My issue is, since my input file has numerous Clients (Sponsor -  N1 - 1000A), EDI standards only allows max occur = 1. If i hardcode the value on the outbound EDI schema the file will work, but if i map to it, it will not. Is there a way (functoid, multiple schemas....)to insert the Sponsor from the input file into the output EDI N1 Loop 1000A N104 ... EX: in the XML the 'GroupPolicyNumber' is what im trying to get into the N104 on the 834. Each record on the input file will/may have a different value 'GroupPolicyNumber'

Answer (score 0):

Your 834 file can have multiple ST-SE in the file. In each ST-SE you can have a valid N1-1000A.